# How can i check if the lines are identical?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private bool displayed;
private void PostMessage()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.words.Length; x++)
        {
            if (ScrollLabel._lines[i].Contains(WordsList.words[x]) && !displayed)
            {
                displayed = true;
                lineToPost = ScrollLabel._lines[i];
                PostFacebookWall(LongaccessToken, lineToPost + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "נשלח באופן אוטומטי כניסיון דרך תוכנה");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. I call this method in a timer tick event every second.

   - But if the variable string `lineToPost` is identical it will not send it again.
     But it might be a situation that the `lineToPost` may contain the exact same word inside but the whole line is not the same so i want to send it.
   - Only if the whole line is the same, then don't make the `postFacebookWall`
   - If the whole line is not the same but the same word is the line as in other line(s), then use the `PostFacebookWall` method.
2. I'm using a `bool` variable so it will not send the same line over and over again.

   - I would like it to send the line(s) once, regardless if there is only one line or if there are more than one line.

The problem is the way I'm using the `bool` now, it will send a line and then will never send any other line at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your problem, you can store sent lines to detect that there was no changes.

```
// key: line index, value: sent line 
private Dictionary<int, string> sent = new Dictionary<int, string>();

private void PostMessage()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var line = ScrollLabel._lines[i];

        if(sent.ContainsKey(i) && sent[i] == line) continue;

        sent[i] = line;

        if (WordsList.Any(line.Contains))                           
          PostFacebookWall(LongaccessToken, line + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine 
                                                 + "נשלח באופן אוטומטי כניסיון דרך תוכנה");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are close but not close enough, `GetHashCode()` tells you the two lines "might" be equal, but it does not tell you for sure. It is very possible for two totally different strings to have the same hash code. Change it to a `Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>` and I think this solution would work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yeah, you are right, although I doubt he will have problems with his app. Why did you say `HashSet<string>` should be dictionary value? There is only one string per index, i'd use  `string`

Comment: I thought there could be more than one string per index.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I oversee something, but I'd simply remember the last line in a string variable and only execute the inner for loop if the current line is different to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very well suited to [Reactive Extensions](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html). Using Rx, you could decouple the pushing of lines to the actual send action.

You would probably have a class that exposes an `IObservable<Line>` and another one which is responsible for sending. In the sender, you would subscribe to the observable, stating that you want new lines only if it is different than the last pushed one. You can use [`DistinctUntilChanged`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bnaya/2012/02/02/rx-distinctuntilchanged/) for this.

Rx is a complex framework to understand though. If this is some sort of toy example and you don't know about Rx, I'd probably keep one of the other posted solutions. If this is a more serious/professional work though, I'd thoroughly consider that approach as it is *much* more elegant and simple to implement and maintain.